Printing specific pages of an epub with Calibre
Apparently there is no plugin for Calibre to convert the epub3 into images which would keep the flow of text seen in the reader.
Therefore, I've tried to print the epub with the 64-bit version, but the process never ends...
Additionally, Calibre's viewer stays in a small size regardless of any configurations of width, so I cannot screenshot page by page at that miniscule size.
BTW, can't Calibre print batches of specific "pages" as rendered in the reader?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Calibre simply won't convert, even using the latest 64-bit versions, to any format (currently no conversion to images is available!), nor will it print any fixed layout epub3.
Adobe Digital Editions and Calibre allow connection to android readers:  digitize it by screenshots on your phone and,  finally, OCR it with Abby Finereader.
I suggest reporting the issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre.

Calibre has no problem converting ePub to PDF. What fails is the underlying system resources. This is done on old 32bit system where I have to switch off QT functions and thus the results with such high density images may be limited. Basically the file needs more resources than the machine can deliver. So here is stuck at 47% when it tries to use the fonts.

I would suggest since the example given is very well published, in many formats, that the best solution is to search (or buy) an already converted copy. The example shown on the right was actually done very much by hand after several aborted partial attempts with other applications.
Here SumatraPDF can very easily read the official PDF sampler of that edition. Or a Calibre Export from PDF to ePub but the pages will be wrong layout.


Okular was mentioned but that also has issue with what fonts to use and where to place them.

I will also suggest there are other converters of e-Books and although it was mentioned in comments that SumatraPDF (Which I support) can read and export many formats. I will show why it may be best in some cases but perhaps not in this case, since output is usually as images.
SumatraPDF is NOT designed as a "converter", although it could/can convert many formats using GhostScript print to PNG JPEG BMP etc. or MS "Image to PDF /XPS".
In this case, I can easily convert ePub to Multipage Mono Tiff via MS Native Image Printing drivers. Or with any Virtual Colour printer such as GhostScript could produce coloured files. The Calibre demo file "calibre ePub demo - Kovid Goyal.epub" can be compressed from 306 KB (313,361 bytes) to 214 KB (219,896 bytes) as a Readable Demo.CB[TIF]Z (TiffInZip)

It can be command line driven, for the desired selected pages, however those methods are not as simple as more dedicated command-line converters.
Answer
Thus my suggestion was use the underlying MuPDF command line "Read and Write" tools such as MuPDF "Mutool" or MuRaster ?.

mutool convert -F png -o fred%d.png "C:\Users\K\source\repos\mupdf\platform\win32\Release\calibre ePub demo - Kovid Goyal.epub" 1,5-7
tar -acf new.zip fred?.png & ren new.zip new.cbz


However due to the odd scaling with this type of CSS the output is not usable although I used some of its editing clean-up features to get a half decent result. The file has been modified oddly especially the font sizes.

Wont' work with epub3 (fixed lay.out) It'd be better to use Calibre's Content server and digitize it by screenshots on android; finally, OCR with Abby Finereader
